# Slide multi-level menu and breadcrumbs in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Does anyone know how I could modify the following code to make a sliding multi-level menu and breadcrumbs in Angular, like this [facebook help](https://www.facebook.com/help/) page?

My basic html code is like this:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#">Electronics</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">back</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Phones</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Furniture</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">back</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Living Room</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bookshelves</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Patio</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the sliding menu, there are a ton of solutions out there.  Here are some links:

http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/
http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/css3-sliding-menu/index.html

To stay in the angular world you can switch out partials in different states or use something like ng-switch.  There are really so many options it is difficult to give you a single answer.

In regards to the breadcrumbs, here are a few nice pre-built options:

[jsc-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/jacobscarter/jsc-breadcrumbs) - [a blog post with instructions](http://strangemilk.com/breadcrumbs-angular/)
[angular-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb)